# Trying to build from Unity to Xcode for a 3D Scanning app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality

I've built a small app that uses the iPhone's 3D scanning functionalities. I was able to do exactly what I did to build this app and run it previously and everything was fine, but now when I try it again on a new build Xcode gives me this error:

'Sandbox: il2cpp(18716) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/flur/iOS scan test/ios scan test 1/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/libhostfxr.dylib'

I'm pretty new to Unity and Xcode so I am not sure what is going on, any help would be amazing!

I have the proper signing for my app, I have also tried to give read and write access to folders and files that are being specified but that did nothing. My build settings in Unity are exactly the same as what I had them when the build worked, specifically the appropriate player configurations in the project settings. I'm working with the packages AR Foundation 5.0.7, Apple ARkit XR Plugin 5.0.7, and XR Plugin Management 4.3.3. My Unity version is 2022.3.9f1 and my Xcode is version 15.0.